# Change color of text within a WinForms RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox that I write a string to every time I click a Form button. Each string begins with the string "Long" or "Short" and ends with a newline. Each time I add a string, it appends to the bottom of the RichTextBox.  I'd like to color each line red if it beings with "Long" and blue if it begins with "Short". How can I do this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Sure, so what you can do is use the SelectionStart, SelectionLength and SelectionColor properties to accomplish this.  It works quite well.

Check out [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox_members.aspx) for info on these properties.

You can know the length of the RichTextBox text and color this as you go by setting the SelectionStart property to the current length, get the Length of the string you are going to append, set the SelectionLength and then set the SelectionColor as appropriate.  Rinse and repeat for each string added.

```
int length = richTextBox.TextLength;  // at end of text
richTextBox.AppendText(mystring);
richTextBox.SelectionStart = length;
richTextBox.SelectionLength = mystring.Length;
richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

Something like that.  That's how I remember it working.

Comment: Nice answer you give me ideo who i can make it (basic format i look view).
- I wanna make some bacis format and coloring `CODE` inside textBoxs. Is there some quick solution like some free/open source control (maybe nudget manager) who can do nice formating job ?

Answer (score 41):

I was just doing this in a program I was writing.  I was doing something like @itsmatt but I feel a bit simpler. You are able to just set the `Selectioncolor` and from that point on the `RichTextBox` will be that color until you change it to something else.  If you are testing every line this seems to work out well and is easy.

```
if(myString == "Long") 
{ 
  richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red; 
}
else
{
  richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Green
}
richTextBox.AppendText(myString);
```

Comment: I like this method. It feels more efficient than appending the text and then going back and making it a different colour, plus you don't need to worry about selection starts/lengths.

Comment: +1 because this is simpler and more elegant than the accepted answer.