# Bold an entire string C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox, bold

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format text in Rich Text Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077582/format-text-in-rich-text-box)

I have a rich text box and a string that I get from a user inputting it into a text box. I want to take that string and bold it all. Any ideas?

Here is the string I have now and it's format:

```
if (InputBox("Please enter a username", "Username:", ref value) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    usr = string.Format("[" + value + "]: ", bold);          
}
```

and the bold variable

```
Font bold = new Font(dispBox.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

This method does not currently work for me, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by mbeckish, this seems to be a duplicate to link they have provided. But to summarize, your issue is that you are not using the properties/methods associated with a RichTextBox in order to get the string formatted the way you would like.

You will need to use the [SelectionFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont.aspx)  Property in order to achieve what you are looking to do.