# How do I output a character array to a textfile?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a map for an RPG game and it was originally built for a console application. The code for the map is here: http://pastebin.com/R6jyT3vw

The main method was used to Initialise the map, Add Rooms and then display the Map. I'm trying to create an RPG using windows forms, and I wanted to display this map in a richtextbox. I figure the easiest way to do this would be to output the array to a text file and then set the textbox to read that file.

Is this possible to do? I've tried a few things such as a TextWriter:

```
MapForm mapForm = new MapForm();
Console.SetOut(new ControlWriter(mapForm.rtbMap));
mapForm.Show();
string locationName = _player.CurrentLocation.Name;
_player.CurrentLocation.DisplayMap(locationName);
```

But this doesn't exactly format how I want it to. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to format the text? See this question to find out how to format text in `RichTextBox` control - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077582/format-text-in-rich-text-box

Then you can save the contents of `richTextBox1.Rtf` variable to text file.

Comment: I essentially want it to look like this - http://postimg.org/image/rrwgregwz/ - I'm not sure how I would do this using the question you posted (I'm extremely new to C# too..)

Comment: This is how it should look - http://postimg.org/image/3y3ityjfv/ and this is how it currently looks - http://postimg.org/image/owfzvbdp5/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `Textrange` as the `flowdocument` which is bound to the `richtextbox.content` and then use a `streamWriter` to write this to a text document and a `streamReader` to read the `string` back from the document. Once you have read this `string` back you must once again convert it to a `textrange`.

Remember to include `Using System.IO`

Links which will help you learn about these things are below:

[Stream Reader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Stream Writer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Text Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange(v=vs.110).aspx)