# C# Textbox, how to set a specific color for a specific word

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I've been wondering **how do I** do that **if I type "Hello"** **to textbox**, it's color **will be set to yellow**, **however if I type "GoodBoy"** that specific **word will get red.**

Is there a way in C# WinForms **how to set a color of specific words in textbox** whenever you type them. I only know how to change the textbox font color but that always sets the color of all characters in that textbox, so is there a way to set color of a word individually?

Thank you for help.

Comment: You should look in to [RichTextBox Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and [Format text in Rich Text Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077582/format-text-in-rich-text-box)

Comment: [How to color different words with different colors in a RichTextBox while a user is writing and raise an event when that colored text is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48358496/7444103)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't used C# WinForms for a while, but as I remember you have object aka RichTextBox which allows you to do more things (and use more then one style for your text).

You will find more info in this link:
[RichTextBox.SelectedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedtext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_RichTextBox_SelectedText)

Good luck