# Using different font color in same textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, richtextbox

I want to use different color for each character in a TextBox.
Eg: when user types first 10 character it should be black after that red.

How can I do this please help.
I am using using simple VB.NET windows form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible with a TextBox. Use a RichTextBox instead. Instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527700/change-color-of-text-within-a-winforms-richtextbox)