# Change forecolor of a certain line in RichTextBox, if it contains certain text

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

This may be an easy answer but it's just not coming to me at the moment.
My program opens a file and the file does contain comments, I want to make all the text after "//" in a line green.

What I am trying to do is something like this: (It's exactly the same way for commenting in VB.Net but with ')

```
If rtb.contains("//") Then
   'make the text after '//' green
End If
```

Comment: You mean how do you do this in a textbox control? If you're using windows forms then the below link will give you the answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527700/change-color-of-text-within-a-winforms-richtextbox

Comment: @ShadowLiberal eh not quite. You know how if you type "//this is now a comment" in c# and the text after the // turns green (including the //), that's what I am trying to do for my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming existing text, you can run through the Lines array to inspect the text:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
  Dim s As String = RichTextBox1.Lines(i)
  Dim index As Integer = s.IndexOf("//")
  If index > -1 Then
    Dim length As Integer = s.Length - index
    index += RichTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i)
    RichTextBox1.Select(index, length)
    RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green
  End If
Next
RichTextBox1.Select(0, 0)
```

Comment: You need to add "+2" without quotes after the index here:
RichTextBox1.Select(index +2, length) to meet the OP's request.

Comment: @SomeNickName Usually the slashes get the same color as the comment.  See the OP's comment to ShadowLiberal up above: `(including the //)`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see that.. then your solution is perfect :p

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Textbox? If so, you need to use a RichTextbox to do what you want.
Like this:

[image]

'Sets the selectionstart character
'Sets the number of selected characters after the selecionstart character
'Sets the selection color

Edit: Oh you wanted after the "\\" characters, misread, use the @LarsTech answer i think.